# What is a counter and how is it used in Python loops?

Tags: python

Can someone explain to me what is a counter ?

So i have these two examples:

```py
n=0
while n < 5:
    print(n)
    n=n+1
```

```py
mysum =0 
for i in range(7,10):
    mysum += i
print(mysum)
```

It says that for use a counter inside the loop, while for while, you need to set up the while outside of the loop, but it didint explain what is a Counter at all, and i am very confused of what is the counter in while and for.

I tried search it online ,and i got counter is the one telling how many times the iteration happens, which I am stil unlcear

Comment: A counter does exactly what it sounds like, it counts.  So, you can use it as a mechanism to know what iteration of the loop youre on.  Similarly, you can in some cases, use it for accessing or changing contents at a specific place in an List.

Comment: In this case it's just a variable; don't be confused with `collections.Counter`

Comment: Do you mean [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)? Here `n` might be construed as a counter by some definition, but `i` is just an element in a range. Generally a counter is incremented each loop, either explicitly or implicitly, and is used as a loop termination condition.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the counter is something that counts whenever there exits a condition or you want to apply it for the process that repeats more than one time. As printing a sum of 100 numbers then you must require a counter to reach the number 100.

```
n=0
while n < 5:
    print(n)
    n=n+1
```

So far in your 1st code **n** is behaving as a counter though it's just a number taken from the user or as input, it will work till your condition is fulfilled like printing the sum of numbers till they are less than 5.

```
mysum =0 
for i in range(7,10):
    mysum += i
print(mysum)
```

But for the 2nd code **i** is behaving as a counter variable as for **for loop** counter element should be present there. So it will run that number of times as declared by the counter.

Comment: I cant cast a vote yet, so just wnat to thank you for responding

Answer (score 0):

A counter keeps count of how many times the program iterates through the loop. **In your first code example, the variable `n` is the counter. In your second example, `i` is the counter**.

In many programming languages (such as Python), `for`-loops make it simpler to write loops that involve a counter. However, in Python in particular, `for`-loops can be used for many other things too.